# ffmpeg FLAC decoding error

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, flac

I am using `ffmpeg` to convert some FLAC files to other format, but it stops at this error

```
ffmpeg version git-2017-03-23-1a5631d Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 50.100 / 55. 50.100
  libavcodec     57. 85.101 / 57. 85.101
  libavformat    57. 67.100 / 57. 67.100
  libavdevice    57.  3.101 / 57.  3.101
  libavfilter     6. 78.100 /  6. 78.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
Input #0, flac, from 'input.flac':
  Metadata:
  Duration: 00:04:11.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2534 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 96000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (flac (native) -> flac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, flac, to 'output.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.67.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 96000 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bit), 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.85.101 flac
Assertion ret <= avpkt->size failed at libavcodec/utils.c:2507157x
```

The error happens regardless of output format and it works fine with `mp3` input files, so I think it's my FLAC decoder.

```
~/tmp → ffmpeg -decoders | grep flac
ffmpeg version git-2017-03-23-1a5631d Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 50.100 / 55. 50.100
  libavcodec     57. 85.101 / 57. 85.101
  libavformat    57. 67.100 / 57. 67.100
  libavdevice    57.  3.101 / 57.  3.101
  libavfilter     6. 78.100 /  6. 78.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
316: AF...D flac                 FLAC (Free Lossless Audio Codec)
```

What should I look for now?

Comment: Please provide a sample input file so we can investigate.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Any FLAC file results in error, I just tried the one at http://www.eclassical.com/custom/eclassical/files/BIS1536-001-flac_24.flac

Comment: No luck with the 16 bit file either :( 

http://www.eclassical.com/custom/eclassical/files/BIS1536-001-flac_16.flac

Comment: I used the Docker image as a workaround, still unsure what's wrong with the FLAC decoder.

Comment: How can I duplicate this issue? I can't duplicate it when decoding with the same FFmpeg version 1a5631dc71 on Linux x86_64: `ffmpeg -i input.flac -f null -`

Comment: @LordNeckbeard this is a problem with the flac decoder on my machine, not with `ffmeg`, I cant re-produce it in my Docker image either. I am asking because I have no clue where to begin tracing this issue.

Comment: You're using the native FFmpeg FLAC decoder.